# error(211): [fatal] rule conditions has non-LL(*)

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3, antlrworks

I use ANTLR to create a grammar, but I get this error

```
error(211): [fatal] rule conditions has non-LL(*)  decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.
```

my grammar rules:

```
conditions
    :    '(' conditions ')' 
    |     condition (C_BINARY_OPERATOR conditions)?   
    ;
condition
    :   expression C_CONDITIONAL_OPERATOR expression
    ;

expression
    :   (term) (('+'|'-')  term)*
    ;

term
    :   (factor) (('*' | '/') factor)*
    ;

factor
    :   C_ID
    |   C_NUMBERS
    |   '(' expression ')'
    ;

// Binary Operators for Logical Calculation 
C_BINARY_OPERATOR
    :   '&&'
    |   '||'
    ;

// Conditonal Operators
C_CONDITIONAL_OPERATOR
    :   '>'
    |   '<'
    |   '=='
    |   '!='
    |   '=<'
    |   '=>'
    ;
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error does say "Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option".  Is that confusing?

Answer (score 1):

See this [page](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/How+to+remove+global+backtracking+from+your+grammar) on the ANTLR website. It has information on how to fix your error.